# Replace localhost to domain name

Tags: php, symfony, dns

I am working on localhost right now. Suppose I have a route now at `http://localhost:8000/info`. Now I have a domain named `www.helloyou.com`. 
In my project routing the routing for this `info.php` class is like `/info`.

How can I change `http://localhost:8000/info` to `http://admin.helloyou.com/info`. I am working on a Symfony environment.

Comment: http://www.complete-concrete-concise.com/web-tools/how-to-change-localhost-to-a-domain-name

Answer (score 3):

In your Windows HOSTS file you can set a mapping from your domain to your localhost (127.0.0.1):

```
127.0.0.1   example.com
```

Located in `C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\DRIVERS\ETC\HOSTS` (On most other systems (Linux/OSX) it's under /etc/hosts)

Any requests for `example.com` will then go to your localhost - this is suitable for testing just on your local machine.

---

If you want to be able to test this from *any machine* on your LAN (including phones, tablets, etc.) then you can set an `A` record in the DNS Zone for that domain (perhaps for a `localtest.` subdomain) that points to the *internal* IP address of your server. eg. `192.168.1.20`.

Comment: We're not sure if the OP is on Windows. There's no mentioning of that. On most other systems (Linux/OSX) it's under `/etc/hosts`, but works the same way.

Answer (score 1):

You need to go to your online management panel.
There you'll find something like DNS.

You add an A record from `admin.helloyou.com` to your public ip address.
Wait till all the caching servers are updated (can take 48 hours).

After this, your public device is visible trough admin.helloyou.com.

Now you need to go to your router (mostly 192.168.0.1).
Go to the page where you can set up NAT/PAT port forwarding (virtual server is a common name for this).
There you need to forward port 80 (public) to port 8000 (private) to your private address.

On your PC you need to allow public access to port 8000 in your firewall.

In the case that you don't have a NAT-router, but are directly connected, you cannot do this second step.
In that case you will always need to surf to port 8000, or let apache listen on port 80.